# Como incorporar o sufixo do nome de um output na função input$...._rows_selected?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

Eu estou construindo uma função no R shiny e nesta função quero pegar o sufixo do nome de um `output$sufixo` e incorporá-lo em uma função do DT `input$sufix_rows_selected`. Alguem tem alguma ideia do que eu estou fazendo errado?

Eu tentei:

```
f.drilldata <- function(base.summary, base.drilldown,  sufix.output, group_var){ 

group = enquo(group_var)
base.summary = base.summary %>% mutate(var = !!group)
base.drilldown = base.drilldown %>% mutate(var = !!group)

input = paste0(sufix.output,'_rows_selected')

validate(need(length(input[[input]]) > 0, ''))
selected_rows <- base.summary[as.integer(input[[input]]), ]$var

base.drilldown[base.drilldown$var %in% selected_rows, ]
}
```

Example do erro utilizando uma tabela nativa do R:

```
library("dplyr")
library("shiny")
library("DT")

tbl.summary <- group_by(iris, Species) %>% summarise(Count = n())
tbl.drilldown <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
DTOutput("output.summary.name")
, DTOutput("output.drilldown.name"))

server <- function(input, output){

# display the data that is available to be drilled down
output$output.summary.name <- renderDT(tbl.summary)

# subset the records to the row that was clicked through f.drilldata function
drilldata <- reactive({ f.drilldata(tbl.summary, tbl.drilldown, 'output.summary.name', Species)  })

# display the subsetted data
output$output.drilldown.name <- renderDT(drilldata())}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Original funcionando fora da função f.drilldata

```
library("dplyr")
library("shiny")
library("DT")

tbl.summary <- group_by(iris, Species) %>% summarise(Count = n())
tbl.drilldown <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
DTOutput("output.summary.name")
, DTOutput("output.drilldown.name"))


server <- function(input, output){

output$output.summary.name <- renderDT(tbl.summary)

drilldata <- reactive({ validate( need(length(input$output.summary.name_rows_selected) > 0, "Select rows to drill down!")) 
selected_species <- 
tbl.summary[as.integer(input$output.summary.name_rows_selected), ]$Species
tbl.drilldown[tbl.drilldown$Species %in% selected_species, ]  })

output$output.drilldown.name <- renderDT(drilldata())}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução simples para esta função. Apenas adicionei o input completo como um argumento da função e funcionou!

library("dplyr")
library("shiny")
library("DT")

```
f.drilldata <- function(base.summary, base.drilldown,  input, group_var){ 
group = enquo(group_var)
base.summary = base.summary %>% mutate(var = !!group)
base.drilldown = base.drilldown %>% mutate(var = !!group)

validate(need(length(input) > 0, ''))
selected_rows <- base.summary[as.integer(input), ]$var
base.drilldown[base.drilldown$var %in% selected_rows, ]
}

tbl.summary <- group_by(iris, Species) %>% summarise(Count = n())
tbl.drilldown <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
DTOutput("output.summary.name")
, DTOutput("output.drilldown.name"))

server <- function(input, output){
output$output.summary.name <- renderDT(tbl.summary)

drilldata <- reactive({ f.drilldata(tbl.summary, tbl.drilldown, 
                                input$output.summary.name_rows_selected, Species)  })

output$output.drilldown.name <- renderDT(drilldata())}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```